# Why does ruby eval() not work on an iterated value?

Tags: ruby, eval

The following eval statement works:

```
@config = {}
@config['foo'] = 42
variable = "@config['foo']"
eval("#{variable}")
```

However if I have an array of strings and I attempt to eval on each of them, nothing is returned.

```
@config = {}
@config['foo'] = 42
variables = ["@config['foo']", "@config['bar']"]
variables.each do |variable|
  eval("#{variable}")
end
```

Comment: You need to change `each` to `map` in  `variables.each do |variable|`. When you've done so `[42, nil] ` will be returned, `nil` because you haven't initialized `@config['bar']`. `each` always returns its receiver, here, `variables`. With `each`, the value of `eval("#{variable}")` is shot into outer space.

Comment: _"nothing is returned"_ – what return value are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example works. But Ruby works differently as you think.

Ruby returns the value of the last expression and outputs that returned value in IRB for example.

When you run

```
variables.each do |variable|
  eval("#{variable}")
end
```

Then the return value of last expression is the return value of the `each` block and that is `variables` itself.

If you want to see that the block really works you might want to output the evaluated result:

```
variables.each do |variable|
  puts eval("#{variable}")
end
```

Or use `map` instead of `each` to change the return value:

```
variables.map do |variable|
  eval("#{variable}")
end
```

Notes:

- In you example in which `variable` is already a string `eval("#{variable}")` can be simplified to `eval(variable)`
- Using `eval` is extremely dangerous if you are dealing with a string that you do not control (like string read from a file or user input). I advise avoiding `eval` if possible.